# nearest neighbour structure in R

Tags: r, search, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I am looking for a methodology in R to search a 2D point cloud for either n nearest neighbours or neighbours within a given radius (ultimately I'll need to be able to do both). I am used to doing this in Matlab with a kd-tree which quite straightforward and works very well: you grow a tree using `KDTreeSearcher` and then query it with `knnsearch`. The value of this is that once you have created a kd-tree (possibly with a lot of data) you can query it over and over.

In R, I can do a kd-tree search in the following way:

```
library(RANN)

x <- c(1,2.3,3.1,4.1,5)
y <- c(3.2,2.1,4.1,2.5,5)

xy <- cbind(x,y)

xyQ <- cbind(3.5, 3.5) 

nn <- nn2(xy, query = xyQ, radius = 2.0, searchtype = c("radius"),k = 3)
```

which returns

```
$nn.idx
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    4    2

$nn.dists
          [,1]    [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 0.7211103 1.16619 1.843909
```

Here, nn2 grows the kd-tree and searches it in a single step. I would like to get the kd-tree back and be able to query it repeatedly. There are various kd-tree instances in R, some of which do not seem to do what they say they do, but I haven't found one that allows  me to create a kd-tree and then search it repeatedly. I'm not wedded to kd-trees either. If there is another methodology that scales well for big data sets and provides the functionality that I'm looking for I would happily use that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might consider [scipy.spatial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html). One of the strengths of R is to be open to other languages via the [reticulate](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/index.html) package

Comment: A related question that bothers me for a while is, how to create a distance-tree, that can be efficiently updated if coordinates of some points change. My good old C algorithm book describes such methods, but I guess that in the meanwhile it should be something there.

Comment: @Waldi I never did find a solution for this and I am still using the method described above. The code ultimately needs to deployed as part of a shiny app. I'm sure reticulate can be deployed as part of a shiny app but it would add a lot of complexity for a small part of the app.

Comment: @tpetzoldt yes that would also be a nice bit of functionality. It seems that there isn't really a good kd-tree package in R that can provide good versatile functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the package `less` that does what I want. Here is an example using 2 dimensions from the Iris dataset for simplicity:

```
library(less)
data(iris)

#create a kdtree
kdt <- KDTree$new(iris[,1:2])

# generate some query points that are different to those used to create the kdtree
q_data <- iris[1:5,1:2] + array(rnorm(10)*0.1, dim=c(5,2))

# query the previously generated kdtree
kdt$query(query_X = q_data, k = 2)
```

This provides the following output and the kd-tree can be queried repeatedly:

```
$nn.idx
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   18    1
[2,]    2   26
[3,]   31   35
[4,]    4   48
[5,]    5    1

$nn.dists
            [,1]        [,2]
[1,] 0.004237926 0.004237926
[2,] 0.120002276 0.150094233
[3,] 0.041263699 0.109570283
[4,] 0.040680499 0.062131121
[5,] 0.071645687 0.086845071
```

@tpetzoldt: As far as I can see, this package does not provide functionality to add additional data to the tree as per your comment.